# Using Java Class to Invoke Web Service Returns No Results

Tags: java, coldfusion

I am calling a web service from java class . In this java class that works fine I avoid certificate check - since I am calling a web service that asks for Authentication Header data (user name and password given by web service) , I do this with a java class .

Now I want to use this java class from ColdFusion. I upgraded my ColdFusion to use jre 1.7 and I call my java class from ColdFusion like this. The service takes a some_company_number and returns a company data String(adress,Name...)

```
<cfobject action="create" type="Java" class="nbs.PozivServisaNbs" name="myObj">
<cfset ret=myObj.init("some_username","some_password","some_licence")>
<cfset retVal = ret.PozivServisu(ret,"some_company_number")>//calls for class method
<cfoutput>#retVal#</cfoutput>
```

And I get no results from ColdFusion , the path of the class is set ok since when I put
`PozivServisaNbs` instead of `nbs.PozivServisaNbs` I get class not found exception - that is , my class loads fine .What should I do , since I want to call a class from java .

Answer (score 1):

Usually there is more to calling Java classes that involve setting up types for arguments. Here's a couple of strategies to try.

- try <cfdump var="#myObj#" / > ... see what is being instantiated. Is it what you expect?
- Try <cfdump var="#ret#"/ > ... is this what you expect?
- Try using JavaCast() for your args to insure they are being passed as the right type of arg for the function. Sometimes you are stumbling onto a different signature.

Using Java within CF is generally a a process of trial and error. Go slow dumping out each type of class or object as you move through the steps.

Comment: Nothing is printed out when I use <cfdump.../> . I upgraded to java 7, ColdFusion works fine . It may be something to do with my java ColdFusion class settings . I have put the jar file on the right spot and restarted the application service . Nothing is printed...

Comment: `<cfdump var="#myObj#" / >` should print *something*. Unless an error occurs. Did you check the logs? With java objects you occasionally get severe errors that display nothing on screen, so you have to check the log files. Also, presumably you were using 1.6 before you upgraded. Did it work with 1.6?